# Given two integers m and n, where m >= n, how can you create a generator to return all the sliding windows?

Tags: python, arrays, string, rolling-computation, sliding-window

To clarify consider two strings, one of length m and the other of length n.

As an example m = 3 and n = 2, with s1 = abc and s2 = de.

First we compare:

```
 abc 
de
and generate tuple (0, 1) (as a and e are being compared, so give their indices)
```

```
then slide string s2

 abc 
 de
generate (0, 0) {compare a and d} 
generate (1, 1) {compare b and e}
```

```
 slide string s2

 abc 
  de
generate (1, 0) {compare b and d} 
generate (2, 1) {compare c and e}
```

```
 slide string s2

 abc 
   de
generate (2, 0) {compare c and d}
```

so we return generate (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0) in that order

If for example m = 2 and and n = 2

we would generate (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0) using a same method of sliding the smaller string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
m = 3
n = 2

gen = ((j+i, j) 
       for i in range(1-n, m)
       for j in range(max((0, -i)), min((n, m-i))))

for t in gen:
    print(t)
```

giving:

```
(0, 1)
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 0)
```

Here:

- `i` is the offset between the first characters of the two strings (going from -1 to 2 in that order in your example)
- `j` is the index in the second string (s2)

Comment: honestly this is a better answer, that is scalable to large windows as it avoids out-of-range options

Comment: @RichieV Not sure what length of strings the OP is hoping to use it with, but yes, I guess you're right it is better not to generate out-of-range options only to have to filter them out. In practice provided that n is small, it doesn't matter if m is large (because the number of out of range options is independent of m), but the problem would arise if they are both large. Even so, when you talk about scalability, although yes when I tested it your solution is about 3-4 times slower than this (when using m=n), the time complexity is exactly the same O(n^2) for both algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

```
out = (
    (i1, i2)
    for anchor in range(n-1, -m, -1)
    for i1, i2 in enumerate(range(anchor, n))
    if 0 <= i1 < m and 0 <= i2 < n
)
```

testing

```
for m, n in [(3, 2), (2, 2), (5, 3)]:
    out = (
        (i1, i2)
        for anchor in range(n-1, -m, -1)
        for i1, i2 in enumerate(range(anchor, n))
        if 0 <= i1 < m and 0 <= i2 < n
    )
    print(*out, '', sep='\n')
```

Output

```
(0, 1)
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 0)

(0, 1)
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 0)

(0, 2)
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 2)
(1, 0)
(2, 1)
(3, 2)
(2, 0)
(3, 1)
(4, 2)
(3, 0)
(4, 1)
(4, 0)
```

Comment: it seems to be working for some example I've verified; do you know why it might not work?

Comment: Asks for a generator, so change your `[]` to `()` and it should work. Anyway, we both get the same output in those test cases, which is good. Looks like your `anchor` is my `-i`.